# How to organize pyqt code for a GUI using MV pattern?

Tags: qt, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I want to control several power supplies with a computer, therefore I have to make a GUI.
I decided to use pyQt5, and I have installed Eric6 IDE on my windows64 computer.

I have read about Qt's MV pattern derivated from the MVC pattern, in this website: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html. It has little examples of a single model using several views (treeView, tableView ...) and explains that the data is stored in a unique place , whereas there are several places where it is showed.

This MV pattern seems to be well designed for Qt user, however I don't see how it has to be used for my project.

I will have a main window whith the values of tension and current generated by each power supply, and also a menubar to select actions such as configure power supplies.

Do you have any advice? Has anybody already done a similar project and can show me the organization of his code ? 
I have already done a java project following the MVC pattern, but QT seems to have its own MV pattern with its specificities.

Comment: sorry, IHM means GUI in French.

Comment: Qt's MV is mostly used for lists, tables, etc. Using MV for entire forms is not so convenient in Qt, but possible. You need to use `QDataWidgetMapper` to connect other widgets with your model.